# I cannot get the final column in a 2D array to print

Tags: java, arrays

My task is to take the original 2D array, and calculate the weight of each index and create a new array with the new values. I just can't output the final column of the new array

Thank you!

Comment: It would be great if you could include some comments in your code. We are here to solve bugs and not understand undocumented code.

Comment: It is very dangerous to ignore commonly known techniques. Within a for loop if you're cycling through an entire array it will always be `int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++`. The fact you changed the second loop to try and fix the problem is not a good coding strategy. Instead understand what the code is doing and isolate the real problem.

Comment: @ChickenFeet that seems like very sound advice. I'm new to Java so I'm just trying to work my way through it and I guess I skipped over some things. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: No worries! Keep at it :)

Answer (score 2):

Your loops should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < calcWeight.length; i++) {
     // note the calcWeight[i], you´ll get the first dimension length
     // if you leave out the [i] part
     // This way your inner loop would stop at 4 (rather 5 because <=) 
     // instead of its actuall length, 6
     for (int j = 0; j < calcWeight[i].length; j++) {
        ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Just a lucky test that doesn't end up with a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. PS : the difference is a bit discret ;)

Comment: Thank you! Though the final column is all zeroes now. Where should I address that at?

Comment: @jamesrob what are all these `ifs` supposed to do? it rather looks confusing to me. You also shouldnt use `j+1` or `i-1`, this will definetly jump out of bounds for the array access here

Comment: @KevinEsche sorry about that. The ifs are supposed to do different calculations based on which index of the array I'm at. The task is to add the indexes ((i - 1)-(i+1)) + ((j-1)-(j+1 )) for any index

Comment: Make sure you check when accessing elements `[ j + 1 ]`, that you are checking `j != calcWeight[i].length - 1` before doing so. Otherwise you will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`